# How to convert dataframe row data into columns using Pandas

Tags: pandas, dataframe

I am trying to convert the following dataframe with multiple rows (table 1) into multiple columns (table 2) efficiently. Therefore, I am trying to do it without using for loop iterating through all PKs. Can anyone help?

table 1

```
|--------------|-------------|
|      PK      |     Name    |
|--------------|-------------|
|      PK1     |      a      |
|--------------|-------------| 
|      PK1     |      b      |
|--------------|-------------|
|      PK2     |      c      |
|--------------|-------------|
|      PK1     |      d      | 
|--------------|-------------| 
|      PK2     |      e      | 
|--------------|-------------|
```

table 2

```
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      PK      |     Name1    |     Name2    |     Name3    |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      PK1     |       a      |       b      |       d      |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
|      PK2     |       c      |       e      |      NaN     |
|--------------|--------------|--------------|--------------|
```

Comment: check Q10 in the link

Comment: @YOBEN_S. Thanks, i realize for this case, I need to do the pivoting and then do a transpose.